# Vue.js - trying to write a computed to return a substring of my data

Tags: vue.js

I am just learning Vue.js.  I followed a Youtube tutorial on creating a iTunes album search.  I got it all working great.  Now I was just trying to add a single property to each album result to try and learn it better.  Each album data that comes in has a copyright variable in the json.

So here is my code that is working without errors:

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <h1>Results for {{$route.params.id}}</h1>

        <div v-if="albumExists">
            <div v-for="(album, index) in albumData" :key="album.id">
                <Card 
                    :title="album.collectionCensoredName"
                    :image="album.artworkUrl100"
                    :artistName="album.artistName"
                    :year="copyrightYear(album.copyright)"
                    :url="album.artistViewUrl"
                    :color="picker(index)"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <h1>Could Not Find Artist</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Card from '~/components/Card.vue';
export default {
    asyncData({params}) {
        return axios.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${params.id}&entity=album`)
        .then((response) => {
            return {albumData: response.data.results}
        });
    },
    components: {
        Card
    },
    middleware: 'search',
    methods: {
        picker(index) {
            return index % 2 == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue';
        },
        copyrightYear(copyright) {
             return '(' + copyright.slice(2, 6) + ')';
        }
    },
    computed: {
        albumExists() {
            return this.albumData.length > 0;
        },
        // copyrightYear() {
        //     return '(' + this.albumData.copyright.slice(2, 6) + ')';
        // }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now I would like to get the copyright from a computed as that's how I think it should be.  Maybe I'm wrong?  But I would like to just do `:year="copyrightYear"` and then use the commented code in the computed section.  But when I try that, I get `this.albumData.copyright is undefined`.  Any ideas how I can do this with a computed?  Or do I have to use a method for this example?

**UPDATE**
Here is my updated < script > section:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Card from '~/components/Card.vue';
export default {
    asyncData({params}) {
        return axios.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${params.id}&entity=album`)
        .then((response) => {
            return {albumData: response.data.results}
        });
    },
    components: {
        Card
    },
    data() {
        return {
            albumData:null
        }
    },
    middleware: 'search',
    methods: {
        picker(index) {
            return index % 2 == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue';
        },
        // copyrightYear(copyright) {
        //      return '(' + copyright.slice(2, 6) + ')';
        // }
    },
    computed: {
        albumExists() {
            return (this.albumData && this.albumData.length > 0);
        },
        copyrightYear() {
            return '(' + this.albumData.copyright.slice(2, 6) + ')';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting an array so best practice is

```
data() {
 return {
    albumData: []
  }
},
```

For one way binding (only for display) just customize object property and then bind.

```
asyncData({params}) {
    return axios.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${params.id}&entity=album`)
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.data.results && response.data.results.length >0){
        return {
          albumData: response.data.results.map(x => {
             return { 
               artworkUrl100: x.artworkUrl100, 
               artistName: x.artistName, 
               copyrightYear: x.copyright.slice(2, 6), 
               artistViewUrl: x.artistViewUrl  
             }
          })
       }
      }
    });
},
```

Comment: Perfect! This option seems cleaner than doing it in a seperate method.

Answer (score 1):

*albumData* needs to be defined in your component's data, props, or another computed to be reactive.

So when you async resolves, assign the result to this.albumData, but define this.albumData in your data from the start, even if undefined or null.

```
data() {
  return {albumData:null}
},
```

Also, albumExists() should return false if this.albumData is null or undefined.  That will be called before the async returns.

Instead of using a computed function, call your method that you commented out.  It should work after your fix albumExists() to return false if albumData is null

Comment: I have updated the post with my updates.  Still getting same error.

Comment: This was backwards-> do this albumExists() {
            return this.albumData && this.albumData.length > 0;
        },

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to tell the computed function which album we are on.  If that is true, maybe a method is the only way. Like `this.albumData[i].copyright`

Comment: So copyrightYear() is getting called even though albumExists() now returns false?

Comment: try removing the parameter here ->   :year="copyrightYear"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177675/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-steven-spungin).

Comment: Should be working how that you've declared your data and prevented the template from rendering until albumData is set.